# Blur Detection of image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on the blur detection of images. I have used the **variance of the Laplacian method**  in OpenCV.

```
img = cv2.imread(imgPath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
value = cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_64F).var()
```

The function failed in some cases like pixelated blurriness. It shows a higher value for those blur images than the actual clear images. Is there any better approach that detects Pixelated as well as motion blurriness?

Sample images:

This image is much clearer but showing value of **266.79**

[image]

Where as this image showing the value of  **446.51** .

[image]

Also this image seems to be much clearer but showing value only **38.96**

[image]

I need to classify 1st and 3rd one as not blur whereas the second one as a blur.

Comment: Please post example images so we can do our own testing.

Comment: nothing specific to suggest, but [google's hdr+ paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/hdrplusdata.org/en//hdrplus.pdf) says they use "a simple metric based
on gradients in the green channel of the raw input. This follows a general strategy known as lucky imaging [Joshi and Cohen 2010]"

Comment: @fmw42 posted the sample images. Please check.

Comment: The background of image1 has a lot of texture. Whereas the other two have flat nearly constant background. But the outline in image 2 has lots of pixelation, but is not blurred much. So you are picking up on the jaggedness of image 2 rather than the other details. This is a hard problem to separate. Perhaps a larger kernel size might help? Also other measures such as local standard deviation (moving window standard deviation average over the whole image). Sorry, I am not sure how to remove or ignore the pixelation. Search Google for blur detection.

Comment: Still didn't get why image 3 has such a low value. Any idea?

Comment: It has a flat background unlike the first image which has textured background and the second image has pixelation.

Comment: You might try blurring slightly each image and then sharpen by the same amount. That will smooth out some of the pixelation. It will lower all scores, but it may permit them to have more reasonable scores in relation to each other.

Comment: Which blurring and sharpening technique should I use? I found many techniques. As I am new to OpenCV as well as image processing as a whole. Could you please guide?

Comment: Technically, the second image is not blurred. It is in fact a magnified version of a low resolution image, using the nearest-neighbor resampling technique. On the opposite of blur, this creates sharp edges. Hence blur-measurement techniques will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to define a threshold as float, so for every result falling under the threshold == blurry. But if the pixel images shows very high every time, even if not blurry, you could check for another value that is very high. Another way might be to detect focus of the picture.

Comment: I am doing the same. The only problem is it is showing higher value for some pixelated blur image than the clear image.

Comment: are they very much higher? say 10000 vs 1000?

Comment: Not that much, but a blur image has value like around 450 where as clear pic has value around 250.

Comment: getting anywhere? @YashasviRajPant This is just an idea I got after doing some research: what if you blur every image and thereafter code an algorithm to check again, and those still showing high numbers you put in a category == "pixel"? the reason I recommend this is because Laplacian basically check for squares in a image, so pixel pics will always have higher number!

Answer (score 8):

I may be late to answer this one, but here is one potential approach.
The blur_detector library in pypi can be used to identify regions in an image which are sharp vs blurry. Here is the paper on which the library is created: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07478.pdf

The way this library operates is that it looks at every pixel in the image at multiple scales and performs the discrete cosine transform at each scale. These DCT coefficients are then filtered such that we only use the `high frequency` coefficients. All the `high frequency` DCT coefficients at multiple scales are then fused together and sorted to form the `multiscale-fused and sorted high-frequency transform coefficients`
A subset of these sorted coefficients is selected. This is a tunable parameter and user can experiment with it based on the application. The output of the selected DCT coefficients is then sent through a max pooling to retain the maximum activation at multiple scales. This makes the algorithm quite robust to detect blurry areas in an image.

Here are the results that I see on the images that you have provided in the question:
[image]

Note: I have used a face detector from the default cascade_detectors in opencv to select a region of interest. the output of these two approaches (spatial blur detection + face detection) can be used to get the sharpness map in the image.

Here we can see that in the sharp images, the intensity of the pixels in the eyes region is very high, whereas for the blurry image, it is low.

You can threshold this to identify which images are sharp and which images are blurry.

Here is the code snippet which generated the above results:

```
pip install blur_detector
```

---

```
import blur_detector
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

    img = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
    blur_map1 = blur_detector.detectBlur(img, downsampling_factor=1, num_scales=3, scale_start=1)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 4)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(blur_map1, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    img = cv2.imread('2.png', 0)
    blur_map2 = blur_detector.detectBlur(img, downsampling_factor=1, num_scales=3, scale_start=1)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 4)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(blur_map2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    img = cv2.imread('3.png', 0)
    blur_map3 = blur_detector.detectBlur(img, downsampling_factor=1, num_scales=3, scale_start=1)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 4)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(blur_map3, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('a', blur_map1)
    cv2.imshow('b', blur_map2)
    cv2.imshow('c', blur_map3)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

To understand the details about the algorithm regarding the blur detector, please take a look at this github page: https://github.com/Utkarsh-Deshmukh/Spatially-Varying-Blur-Detection-python

Comment: is there any equivalent for this in opencv js ?

Comment: I dont think so. because this is not available in the opencv library yet. This is a custom made library in python which internally uses opencv