# Detect if image is blurry using pytorch android API

Tags: android, kotlin, pytorch

So I am working in this app in which if an officer take a picture of car accident and if this picture is blur, it will no accept it. It will only allow images based on quality and resolution. So after research, I found that I can implement this feature using pytorch in which I will save it in my asset and then write kotlin code based on my logic. I found this link: https://pytorch.org/mobile/android/ However, this link shows image classifier example in which user can detect if the image is a cat or a dog, and this is not what I want.

As an example,

If a police officer take a picture via the app of car accident, the app needs to verify if the image resolution and quality is readable and understandable so when user sees the image taken he/she can tell if it is car accident compared to that of when it is blur image and not clear the app will ask the user to take a picture again.

Any tips please ?

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/jainullas/ImageBlurDetection

Answer (score 2):

For a start you can try to build this using conventional computer vision algorithms.
You will find a few examples trying to implement a similar idea using OpenCV (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233870/blur-detection-of-image-using-opencv)).

If you want to solve such a task through machine learning, you either can try to find a model that is trained to solve such a task online (maybe you can find one if you are lucky), or you have to train such a model yourself.

When using machine learning you need to have a dataset, which in your case you can easily create from a database of images and blurring the examples yourself (see [self-supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-supervised_learning)). You need to decide which machine learning method to use. For a simple detection if an image is blurry, using deep learning and CNNs seems unnecessary. Instead look into extracting some features relating to an images bluriness and use a simple machine learning algorithms such as [k-NN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm).

However I think using machine learning to solve this kind of task is not really necessary. Every digital camera is basically implementing this feature for their [autofocus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autofocus). So I think looking for conventional computer vision solutions with OpenCV, (e.g. edge contrast estimation, [image frequency transforms](https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/dbc/tutorial_py_fourier_transform.html), ...) will get you to your goal quicker.

OpenCV is also available for [Android SDK](https://opencv.org/android/).

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed answer. The reason why I thought of machine learning and Pytorch explicitly is that because pytorch supports android api and my boss requested AI image recognition